# Can understand output [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, timedelta

this is my first post so I apologize for the formatting. 
I got that piece of code I wrote for college and it's for calculating hoy many days, hours and minutes have I lived.

```
def min_vivido(fech_act,fec_nac):
anosViv = (fech_act%10000) - (fec_nac%10000)
mesViv = ((fech_act//10000)%100) - ((fec_nac//10000)%100)
diasViv = ((fech_act//10000)//100) - ((fec_nac//10000)//100)
print(anosViv)
print(anosViv*365)
total_dia = (anosViv * 365) + (mesViv * 30) + diasViv
horas_dias = total_dia * 24
min_dias = horas_dias * 60

return min_dias, horas_dias, total_dia
```

So when I try to print this:

```
print(min_vivido(25072017,11101982))
```

I get that I've lived 12699 days, 304776 hours and 18286560 minutes. The problem is that if I just look at the years between 2017 and 1982, I've lives at least 35 years, and that * 365 is 12775, that without counting extra months and days I've lived.

The strange thing is that if I try to make prints inside my code like

```
print(anosViv) and print(anosViv*365)
```

I get 35 and 12775

Help please, I'm stuck

Comment: Please clarify the issue

Comment: You could Python [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to store dates, and then the [timedelta class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to get the difference between dates.

Comment: Did you print mesViv and diasViv? Perhaps one or both of them are negative? Given that 25 July is a few months before 11 October, you'd need to subtract a few months from the 35 years, which woud be around the 76 days of difference I guess.

Comment: "I've lived 12699 days, 304776 hours and 18286560 minutes.". I assume that you mean "I've lived 12699 days, 304776 hours *or* 18286560 minutes." Otherwise there's (another) misunderstanding here.

Comment: @eventHandler thank you for participating on my first post/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your inputs are `int` values trying to represent the date in DDMMYYYY form, take a look at your `mes_viv` calculation:

```
mesViv = ((fech_act//10000)%100) - ((fec_nac//10000)%100)
```

For your inputs, `25072017` (ISO form 2017-07-25) for `fech_act`, and `11101982` (ISO form 1982-10-11) for birth date `fec_nac`, you're computing:

```
mesViv = ((fech_act//10000)%100) - ((fec_nac//10000)%100)
mesViv = ((25072017//10000)%100) - ((11101982//10000)%100)
mesViv = (2507%100) - (1110%100)
mesViv = (7) - (10)
mesViv = -3
```

The problem is, by performing the computation on years first, you're rounding up on years lived, and correcting it by living the appropriate number of negative months (similar problems occur for days). So your end result is actually correct(ish); you haven't actually finished 35 years, you've lived a little under three months less than 35 years, and therefore the day count should be lower (by somewhere around 60-90 days, and lo and behold, you were off by 76, ignoring leap year issues).

That said, please use [the `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). It will do this more correctly (no negative deltas, handles leap days, etc.) and much more simply.

For example, even without changing your inputs and outputs, you could instead do:

```
import datetime

def numerical_date_to_date(dtint):
    # Factor out conversion from weird int-based format to datetime.date
    daymon, years = divmod(dtint, 10000)
    days, months = divmod(daymon, 100)
    return datetime.date(years, months, days)

def min_vivido(fech_act, fec_nac):
    diff = numerical_date_to_date(fech_act) - numerical_date_to_date(fec_nac)
    horas_dias = diff.days * 24
    min_dias = horas_dias * 60
    return min_dias, horas_dias, diff.days
```

Comment: Oh you are right. That’s exactly the format I’m entering ints DDMMAAAA. So that’s why I’m getting less days. Thank you very much.